# dropdown in input form not selecting

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

i have a simple form that has a drop down

```
<form action="TasksController@store" method="POST">
                <div>
               <div class="textbox-first" style="float:left">
               <label for="taskname"> Task Name </label><br>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Enter task title" name="title" style="width:360px">
                </div>
              <div class="textbox-first" style="float:right;margin-right:0px">
                <label for="priority">Task priority</label><br>
                <select  style="width:380px">
                <option value="urgent" selected="selected">Urgent</option>
                <option value="important">important</option>
                <option value="later">Later</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                </div>
```

the form is not selecting

Comment: What do you mean the form is not selecting? Please edit your question to contain more detailed information. Please Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the dropdown isn't selecting any option

Comment: In what way? When you try to submit the form? Do you have a model of some sort that's suppose to hold the dropdown's value and its not storing? Or is the dropdown not functioning at all and you can't select an option within the dropdown from front-end? I need more context and/or detail in order to help you figure out your problem.

Comment: its the frontend i cant select

Comment: Just copying your code and pasting it into a text file and making it a .html, I'm not having any problems selecting an option from the dropdown from the front-end. Maybe use a different browser.

Comment: its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200541/discussion-between-girlio-salama-and-king11).